# How to make a change in a numeric solution to an ODE after it has been solved?

Tags: numeric, ode, maple, norm

I have two Second Order ODE's of which I want to calculate the error between them using (with Maple)

```
|| B(t) - A(w*t) || = sqrt(int(B(t) - A(w*t) )^2), t = 0..T)
```

Where A(t) is the solution to the system without any time transformation on the input and B(t) is the solution to the system with a time transformation on the input ( the time transformation is wt (w is usually small) and T is a number, not a variable. I would change T to study the error with different time spans).

For example (to help explain my question):

The original ODE is:

```
diff(g(t), t, t) = -(diff(g(t), t))-sin(g(t))*cos(g(t))+sin(t)
```

Let A(t) be the NUMERIC solution to the original ODE (because maple cannot solve it symbolically).

Now, the ODE WITH a transformation of time in the input:

```
diff(y(t), t, t) = -(diff(y(t), t))-sin(y(t))*cos(y(t))+sin(w*t)
```

Let B(t) be the NUMERIC solution to this ODE (because maple cannot solve it symbolically).

My question is: Is there any way to solve the error for different values of w? For this, I would need to change my numeric solution of A(t) to A(wt) after having solved for A(t) numerically. My ultimate goal is to plot the error v.s. the frequency, which is w. When w is 1, there should be no error because there is no change in the system.

I am still relatively new to coding. What I have done, since Maple cannot solve it symbolically, is solve each one numerically (with a specific w. however, I would want to do it for w in the range [0..1.5]). Then I plotted them on the same figure. However, this gives me the numeric value of A(t) NOT A(wt). And, I do not know how to subtract them.

```
sol1 := dsolve([diff(g(t), t, t) = -(diff(g(t), t))- sin(g(t))*cos(g(t))+sin(t), g(0) = 0, (D(g))(0) = 0], numeric);

sol2 := dsolve([diff(y(t), t, t) = -(diff(y(t), t))-sin(y(t))*cos(y(t))+sin(.5*t), y(0) = 0, (D(y))(0) = 0], numeric);

S1 := plots[odeplot](sol1, 0 .. 10, color = red);
S2 := plots[odeplot](sol2, 0 .. 10, color = blue);
display(S1, S2);
```

However, this is not helpful because it is only plotting A(t), NOT A(wt). Likewise, it only plots it, it does not show me the error between them.

I am expecting the error to approach 0 as the frequency, w, approaches 0. I do expect the error to increase when w is in between 0 and 1.

Comment: Let me try to interpret what you want to achieve. You have some differential operator (non-linear) `F[y]=y''+y+0.5*sin(2*y)` and want to compare the solutions for different forcings `F[y](t)=sin(w*t)`. Due to the friction term this forced pendulum will converge to a solution with the same frequency as the forcing. In comparing the solutions, you want to eliminate the frequency differences, so you want to compare `y[w=1](w*t)` with `y[w=w](t)`. Note that you will get also phase and amplitude differences in the limit cycles.

Comment: A mathematical answer is to rescale the equation for `y` so that the forcing is the same. Consider `h(w*t)=y(t)`, then `w*h'(w*t)=y'(t)`, `w^2*h''(w*t)=y''(t)` so that `h''(s)+h'(s)/w+0.5*sin(2*h(s))/w^2=sin(s)/w^2`. Now instead of comparing `y(t)` and `g(w*t)` you can also compare `h(s)` with `g(s)`.

Comment: Thank you @Lutzl, I think you understood me correctly! I will try this out as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to do this. Some are more efficient that others. Some are more convenient. I'll show a few.

This first basic way involves two calls to `dsolve`, similar to your original code, but with the extra `output=listprocedure` option. This makes `dsolve` return a list of scalar-valued procedures rather than a single procedure (which would return a list of values). This allows us to pick off the individual procedures to `y(t)` and `g(t)` and utilize them separately.

```
restart;
sol1 := dsolve([diff(g(t), t, t)
                = -(diff(g(t), t))- sin(g(t))*cos(g(t))+sin(t),
                g(0) = 0, (D(g))(0) = 0], numeric,
                output=listprocedure):
sol2 := dsolve([diff(y(t), t, t)
                = -(diff(y(t), t))-sin(y(t))*cos(y(t))+sin(.5*t),
                y(0) = 0, (D(y))(0) = 0], numeric,
                output=listprocedure):
```

You could still use `plots:-odeplot` here if you wish.

```
S1 := plots:-odeplot(sol1, 0 .. 20, color = red, numpoints=200):
S2 := plots:-odeplot(sol2, 0 .. 20, color = blue, numpoints=200):
plots:-display(S1, S2, size=[400,150]);
```

[image]

But you could also extract the individual procedures, plot them, or plot their difference.

```
G := eval(g(t),sol1):
Y := eval(y(t),sol2):

plot([G,Y], 0..20, color=[red,blue], size=[400,150]);
```

[image]

The difference between them is now easier to plot.

```
plot(G-Y, 0..20, color=black, size=[400,150]);
```

[image]

We can compute a norm (your integral),

```
sqrt(evalf(Int( t -> ( G(t) - Y(t) )^2, 0..20, epsilon=1e-5)));
         8.74648880831735
```

But now let's make it more convenient to treat `w` as a parameter which we adjust on the fly. (We don't want to incur the cost or inconvenience of calling `dsolve` for each value of `w`.)

```
solgen := dsolve([diff(y(t), t, t)
                 = -(diff(y(t), t))-sin(y(t))*cos(y(t))+sin(w*t),
                 y(0) = 0, (D(y))(0) = 0], numeric,
                 parameters = [w],
                 output=listprocedure):

 Ygen := eval(y(t),solgen):

 # set the parameter value
 Ygen(parameters=[w=0.5]);
                       [w = 0.5]

 # we could query the parameter value
 Ygen(parameters);
                       [w = 0.5]

 # Now call it at a particular value of t
 Ygen(3.2);
                   0.864744459594622
```

Now we construct a procedure of both `w` and `t`. When called without numeric arguments it returns unevaluated. When called with numeric arguments it checks whether the `w` value matches the current stored parameter value and if different it sets the stored value. Then it calls the computional procedure `Ygen` at the given `t` value.

```
Yw := proc(t,w)
  if not [t,w]::list(numeric) then
    return 'procname'(args);
  end if;
  if w - eval(':-w',Ygen(parameters)) <> 0.0 then
    Ygen(':-parameters'=[':-w'=w]);
  end if;
  Ygen(t);
end proc:
```

This can produce the same plots as before.

```
plots:-display(
  plot(Yw(t,0.5), t=0..20, color=red),
  plot(Yw(t,1.0), t=0..20, color=blue),
  size=[400,150]
);
```

[image]

```
# somewhat inefficient since for each t value it
# switches the value of the w parameter.
plot(Yw(t,1.0)-Yw(t,0.5), t=0..20, size=[400,150]);
```

[image]

We could also do (joined lines) in point-plots, which is more efficient since all the `t` values are computed in sequence for any given `w` value. (Ie, it doesn't bounce around between `w` values.)

```
a,b := 0,20:
xpts := Vector(100,(i)->a+(b-a)*(i-1)/(100-1),datatype=float[8]):
plots:-display(
  plot(<xpts | map(t->Yw(t,0.5), xpts)>, color=red),
  plot(<xpts | map(t->Yw(t,1.0), xpts)>, color=blue),
  size=[400,150]
);
```

[image]

```
# more efficient since all the Yw values for w=1.0 are
# computed together, and all the Yw values for w=0.5 are
# computed together.
plot(<xpts | map(t->Yw(t,1.0), xpts) - map(t->Yw(t,0.5), xpts)>,
     size=[400,150]);
```

[image]

```
evalf([seq( ['w'=w, sqrt(Int( unapply( (Yw(t,1.0)
                                         - Yw(t,w))^2, t),
                              0..20, epsilon=1e-1))],
             w=0..1.0, 0.1 )]);

    [[w = 0., 2.97123678486962], [w = 0.1, 20.3172660599286], 

     [w = 0.2, 21.8005838723429], [w = 0.3, 13.0097728518328], 

     [w = 0.4, 9.28961600039575], [w = 0.5, 8.74643983270251], 

     [w = 0.6, 6.27082651159143], [w = 0.7, 5.38965679479886], 

     [w = 0.8, 5.21680809275065], [w = 0.9, 3.19786559349464], 

     [w = 1.0, 0.]]


plot(w->sqrt(Int( (Yw(t,1.0) - Yw(t,w))^2, t=0..20,
                  epsilon=1e-3, method=_d01ajc )),
     0..1, size=[400,150]);
```

[image]

```
plot3d( Yw(t,w), w=0..1.0, t=0..50, grid=[179,179] );
```

[image]

```
# For 3D plotting it's also faster to compute all t-values
# for each given w-value, rather than the other way round.
CodeTools:-Usage(
  plot3d( Yw(t,w), w=0..1.0, t=0..50, grid=[49,49] )
):

   memory used=37.51MiB, alloc change=0 bytes, cpu time=504.00ms,
   real time=506.00ms, gc time=127.31ms

CodeTools:-Usage(
  plot3d( Yw(t,w), t=0..50, w=0..1.0, grid=[49,49] ) ):

   memory used=124.13MiB, alloc change=0 bytes, cpu time=2.66s,
   real time=2.66s, gc time=285.47ms
```

[edited]
The plot above of that norm is not fast. Below I make three adjustments for better performance:
 1) Use a dedicated procedure `Yw1` for w=1.0 so that `Yw` will not be called to set the parameter `w` twice for each evaluation of the integrand (in the norm).
 2) Use option remember on that procedure `Yw1`.
 3) Use option `compile=true` in the two `dsolve` calls.

I also correct the formula in the norm to call `Yw1(w*t)`, to match the original formulation in question.

```
restart;
solw1 := dsolve([diff(y(t), t, t)
             = -(diff(y(t), t))-sin(y(t))*cos(y(t))+sin(t),
             y(0) = 0, (D(y))(0) = 0], numeric,
             compile=true,
             output=listprocedure):
Yw1raw := eval(y(t),solw1):
Yw1 := proc(t)
  option remember;
  if not t::numeric then return 'procname'(args); end if;
  []; # evalhf error that plot will catch
  Yw1raw(t);
end proc:
solgen := dsolve([diff(y(t), t, t)
             = -(diff(y(t), t))-sin(y(t))*cos(y(t))+sin(w*t),
             y(0) = 0, (D(y))(0) = 0], numeric,
             parameters = [w],
             compile=true,
             output=listprocedure):
Ygen := eval(y(t),solgen):
Yw := proc(t,w)
  if not [t,w]::list(numeric) then
    return 'procname'(args);
  end if;
  if w - eval(':-w',Ygen(parameters)) <> 0.0 then
    Ygen(':-parameters'=[':-w'=w]);
  end if;
  Ygen(t);
end proc:

CodeTools:-Usage(
  plot(w->sqrt(Int( (Yw1(w*t) - Yw(t,w))^2, t=0..20,
                    epsilon=1e-3, method=_d01ajc )),
       0..1, size=[400,150])
);

    memory used=0.76GiB, alloc change=205.00MiB,
    cpu time=8.22s, real time=7.78s, gc time=761.80ms
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @acer! This really helped. At first, it wasn't exactly doing what I wanted. But, when I changed Yw(t,1.0) to Yw(w*t, 1.0) in: 
    `plot(w->sqrt(Int( (Yw(t,1.0) - Yw(t,w))^2, t=0..20,
                  epsilon=1e-3, method=_d01ajc )),
     0..1, size=[400,150])`; 

it worked perfectly! Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you had it as `A(w*t)` in your original formulation of the norm. By the way, if you add the option `compile=true` to the dsolve call then that plot of the norm (as a function of w) take about 25 secs instead of 35 secs on fast machine, but the results seem acceptably similar. (You can wrap a command with a call to `CodeTools:-Usage` to get additional timing information.)

Comment: I have added a new part at the end, with the corrected formula for the norm as well as performance improvements.